# Selecting specific columns from df -h output in python

Tags: python, parsing, unix

I'm trying to create a simple script that will select specific columns from the unix `df - h` command. I can use awk to do this but how can we do this in python?

Here is `df -h` output:

```
Filesystem                    Size  Used  Avail  Use%  Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_base-lv_root   28G   4.8G    22G   19%  /
tmpfs                        814M   176K   814M    1%  /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                    485M   120M   340M   27%  /boot
```

I want something like:

Column 1:

```
Filesystem
/dev/mapper/vg_base-lv_root           
tmpfs                 
/dev/sda1
```

Column 2:

```
Size
28G
814M 
485M
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`op.popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.popen) to run the command and retrieve its output, then [`splitlines`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) and [`split`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split the lines and fields. Run [`df -Ph`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/df.html) rather than `df -h` so that lines are not split if a column is too long.

```
df_output_lines = [s.split() for s in os.popen("df -Ph").read().splitlines()]
```

The result is a list of lines. To extract the first column, you can use `[line[0] for line in df_output_lines]` (note that columns are numbered from 0) and so on. You may want to use `df_output_lines[1:]` instead of `df_output_lines` to strip the title line.

If you already have the output of `df -h` stored in a file somewhere, you'll need to join the lines first.

```
fixed_df_output = re.sub('\n\s+', ' ', raw_df_output.read())
df_output_lines = [s.split() for s in fixed_df_output.splitlines()]
```

Note that this assumes that neither the filesystem name nor the mount point contain whitespace. If they do (which is possible with some setups on some unix variants), it's practically impossible to parse the output of `df`, even `df -P`. You can use [`os.statvfs`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.statvfs) to obtain information on a given filesystem (this is the Python interface to the [C function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/statvfs.html) that `df` calls internally for each filesystem), but there's no portable way of enumerating the filesystems.

Comment: In addition to os.statvfs Python 3.3 will add a new function [shutil.disk_usage](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/shutil.html#shutil.disk_usage) which returns a named tuple with the attributes total, used and free space.

Comment: Prefer subprocess instead of os.popen, as os.popen is deprecated (http://docs.python.org/library/os#os.popen).

Comment: Thanks @Gilles. I've tried the first option and it worked. I had to do like this for subprocess module. **df_output_lines = [s.split() for s in subprocess.Popen(["df", "-Ph"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip().splitlines()]**

Comment: This does no work if the logical file system name has a space in it, like `map auto_home` or `Mac HD`. The Python split will split on all single spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer to the question, but I tried to solve the problem. :)

```
from os import statvfs

with open("/proc/mounts", "r") as mounts:
    split_mounts = [s.split() for s in mounts.read().splitlines()]

    print "{0:24} {1:24} {2:16} {3:16} {4:15} {5:13}".format(
            "FS", "Mountpoint", "Blocks", "Blocks Free", "Size", "Free")
    for p in split_mounts:
        stat = statvfs(p[1])
        block_size = stat.f_bsize
        blocks_total = stat.f_blocks
        blocks_free = stat.f_bavail

        size_mb = float(blocks_total * block_size) / 1024 / 1024
        free_mb = float(blocks_free * block_size) / 1024 / 1024

        print "{0:24} {1:24} {2:16} {3:16} {4:10.2f}MiB {5:10.2f}MiB".format(
                p[0], p[1], blocks_total, blocks_free, size_mb, free_mb)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete example:

```
import subprocess
import re

p = subprocess.Popen("df -h", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
dfdata, _ = p.communicate()

dfdata = dfdata.decode().replace("Mounted on", "Mounted_on")

columns = [list() for i in range(10)]
for line in dfdata.split("\n"):
    line = re.sub(" +", " ", line)
    for i,l in enumerate(line.split(" ")):
        columns[i].append(l)

print(columns[0])
```

Its assumes that mount points do not contain spaces.

Here is the more complete (and complicated solution) that does not hard-cores number of columns:

```
import subprocess
import re

def yield_lines(data):
    for line in data.split("\n"):
        yield line

def line_to_list(line):
    return re.sub(" +", " ", line).split()

p = subprocess.Popen("df -h", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
dfdata, _ = p.communicate()

dfdata = dfdata.decode().replace("Mounted on", "Mounted_on")

lines = yield_lines(dfdata)

headers = next(lines, line_to_list)

columns = [list() for i in range(len(headers))]
for i,h in enumerate(headers):
    columns[i].append(h)
 
for line in lines:
    for i,l in enumerate(line_to_list(line)):
        columns[i].append(l)

print(columns[0])
```

Comment: Hard-coding the columns as 10 is not recommended. It should be kept dynamic so as to make sure that the code works on various flavors of linux/unix

Comment: You are right of course. I've assumed that question author is a Python beginner and did not want to unnecessarily complicate the answer. I've added alternative code that does not assume number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

Not using os.popen as it is deprecated (http://docs.python.org/library/os#os.popen).

I have put the output of df -h in a file: test.txt and just reading from this file. But, you can read using subprocess too. Just assuming that you are able to read each line of the output of df -h, the following code would help:-

```
f = open('test.txt')

lines = (line.strip() for line in f.readlines())
f.close()    
splittedLines = (line.split() for line in lines)
listOfColumnData = zip(*splittedLines)
for eachColumn in listOfColumnData:
    print eachColumn
```

eachColumn will display the entire column that you want as a list. You can just iterate over it.
If you need, I can give the code for reading the output from df  -h so that you can remove the dependency on test.txt, but, if you go to the subprocess documentation, you can find how to do it easily.

Answer (score 1):

I had a mount point with a space in it.  This threw off most of the examples.  This borrows a lot from @ZarrHai 's [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12027562/2444609) but puts the result in a `dict`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import re
from pprint import pprint

DF_OPTIONS = "-laTh" # remove h if you want bytes.

def yield_lines(data):
    for line in data.split("\n"):
        yield line

def line_to_list(line):
    pattern = re.compile(r"([\w\/\s\-\_]+)\s+(\w+)\s+([\d\.]+?[GKM]|\d+)"
                          "\s+([\d\.]+[GKM]|\d+)\s+([\d\.]+[GKM]|\d+)\s+"
                          "(\d+%)\s+(.*)")
    matches = pattern.search(line)
    if matches:
        return matches.groups()
    _line = re.sub(r" +", " ", line).split()
    return _line

p = subprocess.Popen(["df", DF_OPTIONS], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
dfdata, _ = p.communicate()

dfdata = dfdata.replace("Mounted on", "Mounted_on")

lines = yield_lines(dfdata)

headers = line_to_list(lines.next())

columns = [list() for i in range(len(headers))]
for i,h in enumerate(headers):
    columns[i].append(h)

grouped = {}
for li, line in enumerate(lines):
    if not line:
        continue
    grouped[li] = {}
    for i,l in enumerate(line_to_list(line)):
        columns[i].append(l)
        key = headers[i].lower().replace("%","")
        grouped[li][key] = l.strip()

pprint(grouped)
```

Comment: You may want to add attribution links to those answers you drew this from.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I don't usually comment on these things.  How would you give attribution?  A link to the original example?

Comment: Yeah, that should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I found this as easy way to do it...

```
df -h |  awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, re

l=[]
p=os.popen('df -h')
for line in p.readlines():
    l.append(re.split(r'\s{2,}',line.strip()))


p.close()

for subl in l:
    print subl
```

Comment: This does not work as we get the following output:-

[['Filesystem', 'Size', 'Used Avail Use% Mounted on'], ['/dev/mapper/vg_base-lv_root', '28G', '4.8G', '22G', '19% /'], ['tmpfs', '814M', '176K', '814M', '1% /dev/shm'], ['/dev
/sda1', '485M', '120M', '340M', '27% /boot']]

There are 2 problems in this code:-
1. The items are not split properly as required, as is evident in the first item of the list l
2. After the problem 1 is solved, user1610085's requirement is to get the data in a transposed format. Your output gives just all the lines splitted, but, not transposed

Comment: I could solve problem 2 by `for i in [line[0] for line in df_output_lines]:
...     print i
`

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've noticed in all systems I've access to: df with option -P prints in whitespace aligned columns. This means that the headers are the same width (padded with whitespace) as the rest of the items. Building on [the7erm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29573032/2319591), this uses the size of the header to ensure that it gets the whole mount point, even if there is a space in it.

This has been tested on Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, and FreeBSD 9.2.

I've solved this two different ways, the first is a direct answer to the OP's question, giving 6 columns, each of which starts with the header, and then has each mountpoint in order below it:

```
import pprint
import subprocess
import re

DF_OPTIONS = "-PlaTh" # remove h if you want bytes.

# Get the entire output of df
dfdata = subprocess.getoutput("df " + DF_OPTIONS)

# Split it based on newlines
lines = dfdata.split("\n")

dfout = {}
headers = []

# Grab the headers, retain whitespace!
# df formats in such a way that each column header has trailing whitespace 
# so the header is equal to the maximum column width. We want to retain
# this for len()
headersplit = re.split(r'(\s+)', lines[0].replace("Mounted on","Mounted_on "))
headers = [i+j for i,j in zip(headersplit[0::2],headersplit[1::2])]

for hi,head in enumerate(headers):
  dfout[hi] = [head.strip()]

for line in lines[1:]:
  pos = 0
  dfstruct = {}
  for hi,head in enumerate(headers):
    # For the last item, grab the rest of the line
    if head == headers[-1]:
      item = line[pos:]
    else:
      # Get the current item
      item = line[pos:pos+len(head)]

    pos = pos + len(head)

    #Strip whitespace and add it to the list

    dfstruct[head.strip()] = item.strip()
    dfout[hi].append(item.strip())

pprint.pprint(dfout)
```

The second is more useful to me, and the solution to why I stumbled upon this question in the first place. This puts the information into an array of dicts:

```
import pprint
import subprocess
import re

DF_OPTIONS = "-PlaTh" # remove h if you want bytes.

# Get the entire output of df
dfdata = subprocess.getoutput("df " + DF_OPTIONS)

# Split it based on newlines
lines = dfdata.split("\n")

dfout = []
headers = []

# Grab the headers, retain whitespace!
# df formats in such a way that each column header has trailing whitespace 
# so the header is equal to the maximum column width. We want to retain
# this for len()
headersplit = re.split(r'(\s+)', lines[0].replace("Mounted on","Mounted_on "))
headers = [i+j for i,j in zip(headersplit[0::2],headersplit[1::2])]

for line in lines[1:]:
  pos = 0
  dfstruct = {}
  for head in headers:
    # For the last item, grab the rest of the line
    if head == headers[-1]:
      item = line[pos:]
    else:
      # Get the current item
      item = line[pos:pos+len(head)]

    pos = pos + len(head)
    #Strip whitespace for our own structure
    dfstruct[head.strip()] = item.strip()

  dfout.append(dfstruct)

pprint.pprint(dfout)
```